# How to rename files keeping only the last N characters

Tags: command-line, rename

How would I recursively rename

```
Bluebellgray 19707 Rug P1.jpg
Bluebellgray Amal 1972407 Rug R1.jpg
Bluebellgray Random 1907 Rug R2.jpg
Words Amal 1707 Rug R3.jpg
Whatever 9707 Rug R4.jpg
```

to

```
P1.jpg
R1.jpg
R2.jpg
R3.jpg
R4.jpg
```

I'm only interested in the last 6 characters.

I assume the answer begins with `rename -n` and then some funky regular expression? To get it recursive would I need to pipe and rename?  I'm also only interested in .jpg files.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*In the following, remove the `-n` once you are happy about the proposed transformations.*

With `rename`:

```
rename -n 's/.*(..)\.jpg$/$1.jpg/' *.jpg
```

To make it recurse into subdirectories, you have two options:

1. use a recursive shell glob

   ```
   shopt -s globstar
   rename --nopath -n 's/.*(..)\.jpg$/$1.jpg/' **/*.jpg
   ```
2. use `find`

   ```
   find . -name '*.jpg' -execdir rename --nopath -n 's/.*(..)\.jpg$/$1.jpg/' {} +
   ```

**Note the addition of the `--nopath` option to prevent the `rename` command from removing the leading path elements**. An alternative would be to change the leading `.*` of the regular expression pattern to `[^/]*`. Note also that the globstar version will fail if the number of matches is too large (or, more precisely, if the combined argument length exceeds `ARG_MAX`).

---

With `mmv`:

```
mmv -n '*??.jpg' '#2#3.jpg'
```

This one is tricky to make recursive since it does its own pattern matching. It *could* be wrapped in a `find -type d -execdir ...` command I suppose.

---

*Here, remove the `echo` once you are happy about the proposed transformations.*

With a simple shell loop, assuming we may remove everything up to and including the last space character:

```
for f in *.jpg; do echo mv -n -- "$f" "${f##* }"; done
```

You can make this recurse using `find` in the same way as for the `rename` command:

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -execdir sh -c 'for f; do echo mv -n -- "$f" "${f##* }"; done' sh {} +
```

Note that if you want to use the `mv "$f" "${f: -6}"` version suggested in [Raffa's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1312082/how-to-rename-files-keeping-only-the-last-n-characters/1312094?noredirect=1#comment2233236_1312094) you would need to use one of the shells that supports negative substring indexing such as `bash`/`ksh`/`zsh` for the `sh -c` scriptlet.

You *could* use a recursive glob with the shell loop, but you'd need to separate the dirname and basename in order to apply the parameter substitution ex.

```
for f in ./**/*.jpg; do d="${f%/*}"; b="${f##*/}"; echo mv "$f" "$d/${b: -6}"; done
```

Comment: `for f in *; do echo mv "$f" "${f: -6}"; done` should work as well. Remove `echo` to do the renaming.

Comment: @Raffa that's a good point, and closer to the stated intent

Comment: These all work great.  I would also like to do it recursively.  I'll do some research now but if either of you already know (??) that would be great.  Thx

Comment: I haven't found a recursive solution.. so if anyone can help? ta

Comment: if by recursive you mean drilling down subdirectories, a GUI solution is to use krusader, then find all *jpg files, save that list (the option is there on a result) , select all, then file multirename ie krename (requires install krename) and type in R then add a counter or type # or ## for two digits starts with 01, etc.

Comment: @BenRich please see updated answer

Comment: @pierrely Why don't you add this option as an answer?

Comment: @Beast... because I am not sure if the OP wants a terminal command solution rather than gui and mouse clicks. If he says it is an answer I will post a tidied up answer.

Comment: @pierrely Alternative solutions (that work) are always welcome! Sometimes the OP has a specific type of solution in mind, but it could not be the best for their problem (see for example [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)). Furthermore, while a solution might not be the best for the OP, it could be useful for other users with the same or similar issue. So yeah, I encourage you to post your working solution, even if it is a GUI instead of terminal-based solution, but in the end it's your decision if you post it or not. There is no problem if you decide not to. :)

Comment: ok beasty I will do, and for the first time here, if I am able, post some screen dumps of the gui. but not today, car problems in the real world.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your solutions.. I have what I need thanks to you all.  (I wasn't sure about posting a 'thank you' comment given it tells me to avoid such things.. but I thought it important you all know your solutions have worked)